# The time to fix a TV,is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$.What is the probability that a fix take more than 2 hours?

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-function

I got the following question to solve:

> The time to fix a TV in hours, is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$. What is the probability that a fix take more than 2 hours?

The answer is $e^{-1}$. I tried to use some formulas but with no success;

How should such question to be solved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look up the [Cumulative Distribution Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) of the distribution.  $CDF(x)$ is the chance the repair takes less than $x$ time. To get the chance it takes more, subtract from $1$.

Comment: seems to work; thanks!